# Unable to install playonlinux

Tags: 20.04

Err:1 http://mirror.biznetgio.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 libglu1-mesa i386 9.0.1-1build1
404  Not Found [IP: 64:ff9b::673a:6712 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.biznetgio.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libglu/libglu1-mesa_9.0.1-1build1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64:ff9b::673a:6712 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Comment: @N0rbert I haven't reviewed this question yet because there's something that I don't understand. How do you know whether or not http://mirror.biznetgio.com/ubuntu is a legitimate mirror? If you don't know whether or not http://mirror.biznetgio.com/ubuntu is a legitimate mirror then how do you know whether or not noob_coder is using the default repositories but there may be a connectivity issue?

Comment: @karel, the "PT. Biznet Gio Nusantara" is "Two days behind" according to https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors and https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/mirror.biznetgio.com-release . So using default mirror will fix the issue.

Comment: @N0rbert It's only 2 days behind for Ubuntu 20.10 according to https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/mirror.biznetgio.com-release which also says it's up-to-date for 20.04. Clearly there's a communication breakdown somewhere because the mirror is missing at least one file, however the website says that it's up-to-date for 20.04 anyway. If it was just one file that wasn't up-to-date putting that package on hold is an alternative way of solving the error message in the question.

Comment: I think the hammer is beating the thumb in the reviewer popularity contest for this question (see the last paragraph of my answer for the explanation). I have no objection if this was meant to be, but if my answer gets the accept vote I'm going to try to reopen this question anyway.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/mirror.biznetgio.com-release the PT. Biznet Gio Nusantara mirror is up-to-date for 20.04 again, however the latest libglu1-mesa package for i386 architecture is missing from this mirror.

The libglu1-mesa package for amd64 architecture is not missing from this mirror and an earlier version of the latest libglu1-mesa package for i386 architecture for Ubuntu 20.04 is not missing from this mirror either. The only thing that's missing is the *latest* libglu1-mesa package for i386 architecture for 20.04. If you prevented the libglu1-mesa package for i386 from updating with [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/q/18654/) you would probably be able to unhold this package and update it with `sudo apt update` in a few days. This would save you from needlessly downloading ~200MB of files which happens every time you switch download server mirrors.

The linked duplicate answer to the question would also work, but it would be like using a hammer instead of your thumb to push a thumbtack into a corkboard.